# SQL query doesn't return what I expect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

The nested query only show a single row. When I add more data, it throws an error.

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT  
    ListaMaestra.id_ListaMaestra, ListaMaestra.Clave,
    ListaMaestra.Nombre_P, ListaMaestra.Modulo_P,
    ListaMaestra.Caracteristicas, ListaMaestra.Tipo_Formato,
    ListaMaestra.Fecha_Emision, ListaMaestra.Fecha_Revision,
    ListaMaestra.Revision, ListaMaestra.Norma,
    empleado.nombre, cargo.nombre_cargo,
    (SELECT empleado.nombre FROM ListaMaestra, empleado 
     WHERE ListaMaestra.Nombre_Reviso = empleado.id_empleado) AS Nombre_Elaboro,
    (SELECT cargo.nombre_cargo FROM ListaMaestra, cargo  
     WHERE ListaMaestra.Cargo_Reviso = cargo.id_cargo) AS Cargo_Elaboro,
    ListaMaestra.Estatus, ListaMaestra.Ruta_PDF
FROM 
    ListaMaestra, empleado, cargo
WHERE 
    ListaMaestra.Nombre_Elaboro = empleado.id_empleado 
    AND ListaMaestra.Cargo_Elaboro = cargo.id_cargo
```

ERROR:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: please include the error that you in the console

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to select, but the problem should go away if you remove `ListaMaestra` from the `from` clause of each subselect, since you've already referenced `ListaMaestra` in the `from` clause of the main select.   If you can clarify exactly what you're trying to select, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped me a lot and the problem was solved

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @AnibalMelchor - If one of the answers for [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939217/i-am-validating-if-a-resultset-is-empty) resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking it as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should go away if you remove ListaMaestra from the from clause of each subselect, since you've already referenced ListaMaestra in the from clause of the main select.