# I am validating if a resultset is empty

Tags: java, sql-server

I am validating if a resultset is empty.
    if it is empty send a message, but if you have data to show them.
    But he only sends me the second value, the first one is lost

```
if (!rs.next()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The rs is empty");
}else{
    while(rs.next()) {
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString(1));**//only show the second data**
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `ResultSet#next()`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following:

```
if (!rs.next()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The rs is empty");
}else{
    do {
        OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString(1));
    }while(rs.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following:

```
boolean empty = true;
while (rs.next()) {
    empty = false;
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString(1));
}
if (empty) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The rs is empty");
}
```